# Visual Studio won't run my app on windows if the project is stored in an external server

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova

I am developping an angular/ionic application that must be compatible with android, windows (phone and desktop) and Ios. I am currently trying to build and deploy the windows version on debug mode. My project is stored on an external server (disk f:). But everytime I start the app from visual studio (Windows-x64 and local machine in the configuration), I get this error (translated from french) :

```
    "DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF0] erreur 0x80070003 :
  can't open AppxManifest.xml : The system cannot find the path specified."
```

I tried to copy my project on my desktop (disk c:) and when i run the app with this project, the deployment works fine and my app is running well.

I try to give all rights to system, user and administrator on the f: project, but nothing changes. There is no special char on the file path (except underscores). What am I doing wrong ?

(i set up everything in this tutorial https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/win8/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same limitation, and it appears to be a limitation that Microsoft has decided they will not fix, but are considering for a future version.

[Microsoft:  Closed -- Won't Fix: Add network share support](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47577/add-network-share-support.html)

If you open the project properties, select the Build section, and under Output, specifiy a location on your C: drive for the Output path, you won't have to copy the binary files to your desktop manually.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response ! We finally put our projects on our machines.